# Robots in Stage drive through walls

Tags: ros, simulation, ros-kinetic, stage, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that robots in Stage can drive through walls. Is that expected?

I'm using ROS Kinetic under Ubuntu 16.04, as follows:

```
rosrun stage_ros stageros  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/stage/worlds/pioneer_walle.world
```

and

```
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key /turtle1/cmd_vel:=/robot_0/cmd_vel
```

Then, when I command the robot from the telop terminal, it passes straight through the walls in Stage, as if they weren't there.

Stage does print out warning messages about more than one ranger not being supported, but it doesn't sound like that would be related to this problem, right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303285/robots-in-stage-drive-through-walls/) by [The Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5112/the-martin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2018-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-13**:
If you check the topics with `rostopic list` you can see that there are only informations from the `scan`, `odometry`, `cmd_vel` etc.. but none about a collision or a bumper to detect it so it's sound normal.
And yes the warning is simply because there are two robots.

**Comment by [The Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5112/the-martin/) on 2018-09-13**:
But I thought that Stage would still check for collisions, even if the (simulated) robot doesn't have a sensor to detect the collision. If my memory serves me, that's how it used to work in older versions.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-09-13**:
It is possible but you have to implement it and tell the robot to use a bumper (or any other sensor that can tell the robot is touching something)
If you are no restrained to Stage maybe you should use Gazebo.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-09-13**:
@The Martin That's definitely not expected behavior! I'd be curious to see if the p2os version of the pioneer world replicates this behavior. (see p2os_urdf and p2os_launch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

World file objects, like robots and maps usually have a parameter called *obstacle_return*, which makes them collide with other objects around or not. If set to 1, it will collide, and 0 it won't. Please take a look here for deeper info:
https://player-stage-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WORLDFILES/

In the case of your simulation, I could see that the [pioneer_walle.world](https://github.com/rtv/Stage/blob/master/worlds/pioneer_walle.world) includes a [map.inc](https://github.com/rtv/Stage/blob/master/worlds/map.inc) file, and the map described has a obstacle_return parameter set to 0. I believe if you change it to 1, robots should collide with the obstacles.

---

Originally posted by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) with karma: 497 on 2018-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [The Martin](https://answers.ros.org/users/5112/the-martin/) on 2018-09-14**:
Indeed! Strange, though, that all the map files that ship with Stage have `obstacle_return 0`.

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2018-09-18**:
I've added a link the file that has obstacle_return 0